# DataLoader reading string 2800E3 as scientific notation

Tags: data-loader

We are migration a Dynamics environment to SalesForce.

The majority of our data is migrated through DataLoader.

Right now we are facing a issue with strings like 2800E3. Records containing this value in one of the fields are not uploaded.

Going to the logs we found out that it is interpreting this string as a scientific notation (e.g. 2.8E3).

Have anyone seen this behavior before? Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: What is a type of destination field in SF?

Comment: It's a pick list (not sure if this answers you question).

Answer (score 2):

You sure it's Data Loader's fault and not the source application?
If the target field is a text field it works for me just fine.

```
Name,Description
2800E3,2800E3
```

[image]

Maybe it's Excel that is messing up with you, try inspecting the files, putting apostrophe in front of your "number"...

Answer (score 1):

A common issue is exporting with data loader or reports into CSV and then manipulating the CSV in Excel and do a SAVE.  The act of opening (via Excel) and then saving can corrupt values such that the Data Loader sees the value not in its pure form.

A classic example is a 5 digit zip code starting with 0nnnn that when saved becomes a four digit number nnnn.

Other classic examples are ID fields for Order which start with 802 and, in a large data set, sometimes are just numbers that Excel converts to scientific notation.

Solving this depends on the use case.

- You can try a different cell format
- You can avoid editing the CSV in Excel and instead use a text editor
- You can try a different CSV editor like Open Office or Google Sheets and see if you get better results

Answer (score 0):

Its the excel. I came across the same issue a few days a go. Format the cells and change the number to "text". Worked for me.

Comment: Sometimes that's too late and Excel already screwed up the data, for example by cutting out the leading zeroes, converting something to dates and otherwise being "helpful"... Best way for me is to kill it with fire, open up new blank sheet and use Data Import Wizard where you can specify columns...